# Find T* self-adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

Fix $u,x \in V$ and define $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ by $$Tv = \langle v, u \rangle x $$

I am trying to find the adjoint operator, but not sure how to use the inner product properties to get $T*$. Here is what I have so far

Let $w_1, w_2 \in V$. Then $\langle w_1, T^*w_2 \rangle = \langle Tw_1, w_2 \rangle = \langle \langle w_1, u \rangle x, w_2 \rangle$ but not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You start by supposing $T$ is a linear operator $V\to V$ and then you say "define $T$ by..." Do you mean to get rid of the first part and just define $T$ this way for some fixed $u$ and $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using what you have shown

$$\langle w_1,T^\ast w_2\rangle = \langle \langle w_1,u\rangle x,w_2\rangle \underbrace{=}_{\text{linearity 1st arg}} \langle w_1,u\rangle \langle x,w_2\rangle  \underbrace{=}_{\text{linearity 2nd arg}} \langle w_1,\langle x,w_2\rangle u\rangle$$

Comment: Well if $\langle w_1, y\rangle = \langle w_1,z\rangle$ for every $w_1$ what can you say about $y$ and $z$? Try taking the difference of the two sides

Comment: Can you expand more on the linearity 1st arg? It's not clear to me how we are using linearity property to do the manipulations

Comment: for an inner product we have that if $\alpha$ is a scalar and $x,y\in V$ then $\langle \alpha x,y\rangle = \alpha \langle x,y\rangle$. Note that $\langle w_1,u\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ in this case

Comment: oh so the scalar in this sense is $\langle w_1, u \rangle$?

Comment: Yes! This is correct

Comment: Okay thanks for clearing it up. My mistake was thinking since $x$ is fixed, $x$ was the scalar value but that clearly doesn't make sense to me now haha